# Mapping Path Variable to Command Property

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/post/{postThreadId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String paramTest(PostParams params) {
    return params.toString();
}
```

Spring MVC Path Variable `("postThreadID")` can be mapped to Command object field?

PostParams have `setPostThreadId(int ...)`
But, it looks not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible.

Set it manually:

```
public String paramTest(PostParams params, @PathVariable int postThreadId) {
    params.setPostThreadId(postThreadId);
    ....
}
```

Comment: And it shouldn't be working at all, because controllers are singletons.